gtsummary with multi-categorical variable
I would like to summarize a table with a categorical variable, that can more than one category for any given id (i.e., in my example below, a semicolon-separated list within a cell). The denominator should be the number of unique ids (i.e., in my example below, n_ids = 5), and percentages should therefore add to greater than 100%. I'm not sure how to get gtsummary to use my desired denominator. See the reprex and my desired output below. Thank you for your help.
library(gtsummary)

# Create a dataframe with multiple categories per id
df <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~id, ~category, ~success,
    1, "red;blue", TRUE,
    2, "red", TRUE,
    3, "blue", FALSE,
    4, "green", FALSE,
    5, "green;blue", TRUE
  )

# Lengthen to row per category, per id
df_per_category <-
  df |> 
  tidyr::separate_rows(category, sep = ";")

# Create gtsummary table
df_per_category |>
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    include = c(category, success),
    by = success,
    label = list(category ~ "Category"),
    sort = all_categorical() ~ "frequency"
  ) |>
  add_overall()|>
  bold_labels() |> 
  as_kable()




Characteristic
Overall, N = 7
FALSE, N = 2
TRUE, N = 5




Category





blue
3 (43%)
1 (50%)
2 (40%)


green
2 (29%)
1 (50%)
1 (20%)


red
2 (29%)
0 (0%)
2 (40%)



Created on 2024-08-05 with reprex v2.1.1
My desired output:



Characteristic
Overall, N = 5
FALSE, N = 2
TRUE, N = 3




Category





blue
3 (60%)
1 (50%)
2 (67%)


green
2 (40%)
1 (50%)
1 (33%)


red
2 (40%)
0 (0%)
2 (67%)




It's probably better not to lengthen the number of rows to keep the denominator correct.
df |>
  mutate(red=grepl('red', category),
         blue=grepl('blue', category),
         green=grepl('green', category)
  ) |>
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    include = c(red, blue, green, success),
    by = success,
    sort = all_categorical() ~ "frequency"
  ) |>
  add_overall() |>
  bold_labels() 



You could also use your long data frame to get the column names:
vars <- unique(df_per_category$category)    
df[vars] <- sapply(vars, grepl, x=df$category)

select(df, vars, success) |>
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    by = success,
    sort = all_categorical() ~ "frequency"
  ) |>
  add_overall() |>
  modify_column_indent(columns=label,
                   rows=variable!="Category") |>
  modify_table_body(~ .x |>
                      bind_rows(tibble(
                        variable="Category",
                        var_type=NA,
                        var_label="Category",
                        row_type="label",
                        label="Category",
                        stat_0= NA)) |>
  arrange(factor(variable, levels="Category"))) |>
  modify_table_styling(columns = label,
                   rows = variable == "Category",
                   text_format = "bold")




Thanks @Edward. This solution however makes each category/color it's own characteristic and therefore bolded row. I'd like all the colors as indented, unbolded rows under the category header.

I see. Adding the Category header may be tricky. Indentation and non-bolding the levels is straightforward (see edit).

Thanks for the help. Building on your solution, I figured out a hack-y solution to handle the label/level issue, which I'll post.

Yes - both our ways are somewhat hacky. Maybe Daniel Sjoberg has a more elegant method. See my final edit.

Thanks for re-introducing me to the modify_* functions! I made another edit based on that. I'm happy with this for now. Thank you!

Building on @Edward's solution, here's hack-y way to get my desired output. If anyone knows a proper gtsummary way, please do share.
library(gtsummary)

# Create a dataframe with multiple categories per id
df <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~id, ~category, ~success,
    1, "red;blue", TRUE,
    2, "red", TRUE,
    3, "blue", FALSE,
    4, "green", FALSE,
    5, "green;blue", TRUE
  )

df |> 
  
  # Transform table to have row per id/category combination
  tidyr::separate_rows(category, sep = ";") |> 
  
  # Figure out and arrange categories by descending frequency
  # This sorting is for gtsummary 
  mutate(n_category = dplyr::n(), .by = "category") |> 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(n_category)) |> 
  select(-n_category) |> 
  
  # Transform table to have column per level
  dplyr::mutate(value = TRUE) |> 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = value, values_fill = FALSE) |> 
  
  select(-id) |>
  
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    by = success,
    sort = all_categorical() ~ "frequency"
  ) |>
  add_overall() |> 
  bold_labels() |> 
  
  # Manually change categories to levels and add category label
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x |> 
      dplyr::mutate(variable = "category", var_label = "Category", row_type = "level") |> 
      dplyr::add_row(variable = "category", var_type = "dichotomous", var_label = "Category", row_type = "label", label = "Category", .before = 1)
  ) |> 
  as_kable()




Characteristic
Overall, N = 5
FALSE, N = 2
TRUE, N = 3




Category





blue
3 (60%)
1 (50%)
2 (67%)


red
2 (40%)
0 (0%)
2 (67%)


green
2 (40%)
1 (50%)
1 (33%)



Created on 2024-08-06 with reprex v2.1.1
